# Getting data from findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse to get data out of a database. 
When the block - findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is called an array gets passed. As I am only receiving one row of data, it all appears in one [0] section of the array. So how do i get all the bits out of that array ??

Here is some code I working with :

```
var MainPicture = PFQuery(className: "Staff")
        MainPicture.whereKey("Position", equalTo: "Sales Manager")
        MainPicture.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
            if(error == nil){
                for object in objects {

                }
                self.getMainImageData(objects as [PFObject])


            }
            else{
                println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
            }

        })
```

so where **for object in objects** is , it gives me one array with all the stuff in. So how can extract that array to get the First Name, Last Night, location, Staff ID out ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to cast your `[AnyObject]` to a `[PFObject]` and then you can use the standard Parse methods to get the data out.

```
if let staffObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
  for staff in staffObjects {
    // Use staff as a standard PFObject now. e.g.
    let firstName = staff.objectForKey("first_name")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to cast to `PFObject` in the block like this? `MainPicture.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[PFObject]!...` Would Parse ever not return a `PFObject`?

Comment: The method signature for `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` returns a `PFArrayResultBlock`, which has a signature (in Swift) of `([AnyObject]?, NSError?)`. This indicates that objects (`[AnyObject]`) may be nil. A forced cast to `[PFObject]` is probably not a good idea. It should be treated as optional. It would make more sense to do something like `MainPicture.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[PFObject]?...`. That way, you can still check if it's nil or not, and if it's not, you're assured it contains `PFObject`s. It's just moving the casting, as the nil check is still required.