# Parse query returns PFObject rather than subclass on restart

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have the following `PFObject` subclass:

```
class Show: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Show"
    }
}
```

I can then add new `Show` objects as follows:

```
let newShow = Show()
newShow.date = NSDate()
newShow.pinInBackground()
```

And query `Show` objects.

```
let query = Show.query()!
query.fromLocalDatastore()
query.orderByAscending("date")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (shows, error) -> Void in

    println("shows:\(shows)")

    let myShows = shows as? [Show]

    println("myShows:\(myShows)")

    let myObjects = shows as? [PFObject]

    println("myObjects:\(myObjects)")
}
```

which returns `[Show]` as expected:

```
shows:Optional([<Show: 0x7fde6a8ba0f0, objectId: new, localId: local_90293157b4a20c5c> {
    date = "2015-06-01 12:08:16 +0000";
}])

myShows:Optional([<Show: 0x7fde6a8ba0f0, objectId: new, localId: local_90293157b4a20c5c> {
    date = "2015-06-01 12:08:16 +0000";
}])

myObjects:Optional([<Show: 0x7fde6a8ba0f0, objectId: new, localId: local_90293157b4a20c5c> {
    date = "2015-06-01 12:08:16 +0000";
}])
```

However, if I **kill the app**, and then re-run the same query, the resultant array is `[PFObject]` rather than `[Show]`

```
shows:Optional([<Show: 0x7fef632ca2b0, objectId: new, localId: local_c6995edd73e73e10> {
    date = "2015-06-01 12:08:16 +0000";
}])

myShows:nil

myObjects:Optional([<Show: 0x7fef632ca2b0, objectId: new, localId: local_c6995edd73e73e10> {
    date = "2015-06-01 12:08:16 +0000";
}])
```

Am I missing something? Why isn't it returning objects of the correct class after restarting the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I was running the query in the `viewDidLoad` method of my root view controller. Checking the `PFSubclassing` documentation for `registerSubclass`:

> @warning This method must be called before <[Parse
>   setApplicationId:clientKey:]>

Per the examples in the Parse docs, I was overriding the `initialize` method, but this getting called when the query was created, but before the  `appDidFinishLaunching` method which called `setApplicationId:clientKey`

So the key is to run the query later, or register the subclasses earlier!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not saving object to the Parse `database`, only to the `device`, so the object has not actually been `created` yet. `pinInBackground()` is only saving to the `device`, while `saveInBackground()` is saving to the Parse database, thereby, actually creating the object. If you use .saveEventually(), that will pin until the network can be reached to save to the Parse database. But in general - you will not actually create an object by only saving to your device, it must be saved to the Parse database to create.

Comment: I'm querying the local datastore, so I shouldn't have to save to the remote store. The query *does* return objects - they're just the wrong type. And saving the object to the remote store doesn't seem to make any difference when querying the local datastore - it still returns `[PFObject]`

Comment: @AshleyMills check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512006/getting-data-from-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-in-swift

Comment: I think it should be something like this (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)

Comment: Thanks, but it was nothing to do with method signatures, or saving to the remote database. See my answer below.